# SEO for Questions and Answers

Tags: discussion

What is the best way to optimize questions/answers for search?

I just ran into a scenario where I forgot which file/attribute I had to update to make Tridion force refresh all GUI Extension JS and CSS files (I haven't touched Anguilla for a bit).  In Google I typed: "Tridion gui extensions force cache refresh".  I got a handful of articles on GUI Extensions tutorials, but what I was really looking for was this Q&A, which I remember existed from a long time back, and it wasn't on the first page of my search results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654830/what-does-increasing-the-modification-attribute-do

What is the best way to optimize a Q&A for search?  The approaches I am thinking of:

- Create another question with the keywords you expect and link to the already answered one
- Update the existing Q&A with tags and incorporate keywords in the question's verbiage

Answer (score 5):

I always like to include the `site` parameter when searching Google for answers that I know I've seen before on here or Stack Overflow.

For example, if you search:

> Tridion gui extensions force cache refresh
>   site:https://stackoverflow.com/

Then the answer that you were looking for appears third.

Obviously, a lot of these are now on the Tridion Stack Exchange site, so you may have to search both here and SO separately.

Of the two suggestions that you make to improve the questions themselves, I much prefer the second option of updating the existing Q&A with tags and keywords. A lot of this could be achieved by just improving the readability and phrasing of the questions and answers.

Duplicating the questions and/or answers to improve SEO may only server to 'water down' what is already there, and make finding things more difficult.

Answer (score 4):

We also need authoritative links going to the desired answer. If someone could tweet a link to the page or also post a link to the page from a blog, that helps boost the rankings.